# Make 3 divs responsive without media query

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make 3 divs responsive i.e on desktop view these divs are in row and i want to display them in column view in mobile view.I am using flexbox.

I have tried this

```css
.outerdiv{
        display: flex;
        justify-content:space-around;
        padding:0;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin:0;
        align-content:center;
        text-align:center;
 }

  .innerdiv{
         maxWidth: 24.296875%;
        height: auto;
        paddingLeft:auto;
        float:left;
        left:10px;
        flex: 1;
        flexWrap: wrap;
        background: #e3e3e3;
  }
```

```html
     <div class="outerdiv">
     <div class="innerdiv">1</div>
     <div class="innerdiv">2</div>
     <div class="innerdiv">3</div>
     </div>
```

i want to do it without media query.can anyone assist me for this?? thank you.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do it without media queries? And if you don’t want media queries, then _what exactly_ should determine the items’ widths?

Comment: @CBroe so according to you I have to use media queries for this and there is no way to do this without media queries.

Comment: I did not say any such thing anywhere so far. I asked _you_ some questions to help clarify the problem first of all.

Comment: why you accepted the first answer using media query then? It's possible without media query but if you accept any answer you won't get the answer you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My simpliest responsive without mediaqueries using flexbox :

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw; /*set the size of container*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  max-width: 250px; /*set max width of item*/
  min-width: 200px; /*set min width of item*/
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2rem;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="item"></article>
  <article class="item"></article>
  <article class="item"></article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">1</div>
  <div class="innerdiv col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">2</div>
  <div class="innerdiv col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">3</div>
<div>
```

Use Bootstrap Gridsystem

Comment: (_“Use Bootstrap Gridsystem”_ - that does not mean that this does not use media queries though, it would only mean you won’t be specifically writing them yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this :

```
<main class="wrapper">

  <section class="breweries" id="breweries">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <!-- Photo by Quentin Dr on Unsplash -->
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471421298428-1513ab720a8e" alt="Several hands holding beer glasses">
          <figcaption><h3>Billions upon billions</h3></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p>
          Made in the interiors of collapsing stars star stuff harvesting star light venture billions upon billions Drake Equation brain is the seed of intelligence?
        </p>
        <a href="#">Visit Website</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <!-- Photo by Drew Farwell on Unsplash -->
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513309914637-65c20a5962e1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3450&q=80" alt="Several friends doing a toast">
          <figcaption><h3>Drake Equation</h3></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p>
          Another world citizens of distant epochs from which we spring descended from astronomers Orion's sword shores of the cosmic ocean.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Visit Website</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <!-- Photo by Rawpixel on Unsplash -->
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535359056830-d4badde79747?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3402&q=80" alt="Three different glasses of beer">
          <figcaption><h3>Vast cosmic arena</h3></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p>
          Galaxies the ash of stellar alchemy prime number science inconspicuous motes of rock and gas brain is the seed of intelligence.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Visit Website</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
```

USE This CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
        /* Typography imported from Google Fonts */

/* Generic styles */
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .3s;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

li{list-style: none;}


/* breweries styles */
.breweries {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.breweries > ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.breweries > ul > li {
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

.breweries > ul > li > figure {
  max-height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: .5rem;
  border-top-right-radius: .5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.breweries > ul > li > figure > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.breweries > ul > li > figure > figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  width: 100%;
}

.breweries > ul > li > figure > figcaption > h3 {
  color: white;
  padding: .75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.breweries > ul > li > p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 1rem .75rem;
  color: #666666;
}

.breweries > ul > li > a {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}


    </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `flex-direction` in media queries

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.flex-container {
  flex-direction: row;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.flex-container {
  flex-direction: column;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>
```